# Traduções despadronizadas na lista de perguntas

Tags: bug, tradução

Os status das perguntas estão despadronizados. A meu ver todos deveriam estar no **feminino singular** (dado que *pergunta* está elíptico)

Ou seja, a transição proposta é

- modificada -> modificada
- respondida**<del>s</del>** -> respondida
- perguntad**<del>os</del>** +a -> perguntada

O que devo fazer para que essas traduções sejam consertadas?

[image: Traduções fora de padrão]

Comment: Realmente. O "perguntados" é o que está mais errado e mais confunde. Vim falar sobre a mesma coisa e achei sua pergunta, então dei +1.

Comment: **Relacionado**: [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/3635)

Comment: Nessa época o @bigown só tinha 33k, como o tempo passa kkkk

Comment: Acho que as strings são [essa](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40269669?translated=yes&qt=perguntados) e [essa](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40269650?qt=respondidas). Não podemos editar porque já foram revisadas, só um revisor/Gabe.

Comment: @Molx quando é assim geralmente vou na parte de comentários do Transifex e marco como 'Adicionar problema' indicando a tradução correta da string. Quando sobra um tempinho o Gabe vai lá e corrige.